# Git Partial Copy Access Control

Tags: git, access-control, gitolite

I have to deploy a Git repository where several development teams will work together in independent blocks of code. We have a main in-house integration team that can access everything from everyone. However, some third-party developers should not be able to access top level data and code from our company.

It is known that this workflow is difficult to implement in pure git because git assumes that everyone inside a project, with common access to a repository, can access the entire repository with a clone command, under any circunstancies. By construction and its distributive nature, git's lowest user permission is read-only access permission.

Several approaches are recommended over the Internet do deal with this problem, specially with the use of submodules, separating each team under an individual repository. However, solutions like submodules, subtrees and the subrepos project all bring several integration and management complexities that are not desirable. In fact, the use of git features such submodules as an access control system seems like a misuse.

After research, I conclude that Gitolite can be a feasible tool to achieve what I want to. Gitolite has a feature called **partial copy** that denies access of specific branches depending on the set of rules for a set of users. If you define that a user 'bob' will have RW+ access to only the branch 'unstable' under a 'partialCopy' of a main project 'foo', than an integrator developer 'john' could push confidential code to the master without worrying about 'bob' reading it. Actually, 'bob' will not even know that the files under master branch exist.

However, Gitolite is a barebone approach, requiring low level management of repositories, user keys and permission files.

Considering all this: Is there anything similar to the **partial copy** feature under any of the best git suite solutions out there like GitHub, GitLab, Bitbucket, CodeCommit, etc?

The objective is to deploy a git suite with a better repository management, cloud support, tool integration and GUI access for non-technical managers, with the same fine-grained access control found in Gitolite.

Answer (score 2):

Breaking them up into separate repositories is probably the only viable option for your situation.

Partial copy appears to only work on branches. In order for this to work for you, you'd need to remove protected code that already exists from your isolated branches which will cause far worse problems on integration. To do this without giving access to a the original files you'd need to create a baseless branch because a branch is defined as a given commit and all commits reachable from that commit.

Creating a baseless branch introduces the additional problem of merging without a common ancestor and not having the ability to easily share changes to common files made in different branches without merging in code that is intended to be isolated. I've only had limited experience working with baseless branches while doing migrations from other systems, so I'm not even sure how it would deal with so many files in the main line being missing from the isolated line.

Logically, this is the same as implementing submodules in separate repositories, just with a third party tool for access, so it will come with the same integration and management overhead (if not more by running counter to the native design of git).

Addressing some of your concerns, sub-modules are not nearly as bad as many people make out, they are just a little awkward until you get used to them.

If this is not preferred. Using a packages and a package managers is also a good option here if there are a lot of shared components. This gives people access to the functionality without necessarily giving them access to the code if you're working in a compiled language and read-only access to the code in an interpreted language. (I've used this on several very large projects.)

Using multiple repositories for access control is just a slightly more formalized version of the lieutenant/benevolent dictator model used on many very large projects like the Kernel. This keeps your repositories light and manageable as well.

Comment: "Partial copy appears to only work on branches". Indeed. The approach would be to have a devel branch for each team and isolate the master for only the in-house integrators. In that way, none of the third parties would have access to files in the master. Any new branch for a new third-party developer or team would refer for only a directory template and common files. Merging process would be straight forward. The only issue I could predict with this approach is that any integrator has to be careful when commits content to the third-party branches.

Comment: @marcelo.guedes, the only way to accomplish this without sharing the historical code would be to create baseless branches, which is essentially the same as creating a new repo, without the benefits of having a new repo. I'll update the answer with more details.

Comment: this is the code for partial-copy trigger: https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/5c2fe87019dadbecb1883bedd075cd07b07b2078/src/triggers/partial-copy . Could you point it out where in make the branch baseless? I couldn't spot where and how it could be happening, considering it makes a direct fetch from the main repository of everything from the main, then proceed to exclude non-authorized access with deleting reference commands (line 50 and 66; see last topic at https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec for details)

Comment: @marcelo.guedes partial copy doesn't make the branch baseless, making the branch baseless is the only way to prevent code from the main branch being send to the restricted users. Branching off master and making two commits doesn't create a branch with 2 commits, it creates a branch with every commit on master, plus two extra commits.

Comment: And if all the branches would be from a root from the master? Consider a new repo, then a push with a directory structure template. In that push, it will only be present empty directories with .gitignore files and some basic common files. From that point, and only that point, third-party branches would be created. Anything restricted can be added to the master afterwards. Any new branch should be a hard branch from that same root point with the templates. Do you see issues in that strategy?

Comment: @marcelo.guedes Theoretically, maybe, but would require at least as much setup as separating multiple repos. Modifications to common files would be an issue, without the ability to merge back from the mainline, you'll be in a situation of endless cherry picking commits (which must be atomic to avoid contamination). You'll also run into the code divergence problem, "the probability of a conflict is multiplied by commits on source since merge base times commits on destination since merge base." The longer they run apart, the more likely conflicts will become.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding isn't quite correct. Gitolite's [partial copy feature](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/list-non-core/#partial-copy-selective-read-control-for-branches) simply creates another repository that is contains all but the forbidden branches. Pushes to the main repository are auto-pushed to the partial copy repo and pushes to the partial copy repo are pushed back to the main repo.

Gitolite is really just a set of very good perl wrappers around git to facilitate access control, etc. As such, there is no magic there. (For example, some tools like gerrit that re-implement their own git server can do clever things with refs. gitolite does no such things, it uses stock git.) So anything that gitolite does, you should be able to do yourself, if you really want to.

You can see how gitolite does it in the two scripts below. As per the documentation I linked to, the VREF is executed as an 'update hook' for the partial copy repo. The trigger code is executed as a 'post-receive hook' for the main repository.

https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/VREF/partial-copy

https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/triggers/partial-copy

I would imagine you could implement this yourself on any git hosting software that allows you to install your own hooks. The only change you would need to make is that the `gitolite access` function would not be there, you would need to write something yourself to encode the branch rules that you want.