# git : How to allow access to only some folders (not all repo)? Repo is on windows server

Tags: git

I want to create a repo on windows server for several project that many developers work but i don't want to let any developer can access all repo.
Let say i have 3 project and 4 developers:

project_a, project_b, project_c,
dev_a, dev_a, dev_c, dev_d.

dev_a, dev_b can work on project_a and project_b but not on project_c
dev_c, dev_d can work on project_b and project_c but not on project_a

All have windows machine and server is also windows.
How can I create such structure? 
I tried windows share permissions for project folders on git repo but developers couldn't use git specs.
There is gitolite but it is for unix. I can try cygwin on server but what about clients?
Please let me know if there is a solution.
Thank you

Comment: is it necessary that all three projects go to the same repo? perhaps all three projects can be git submodules of the main project repo?

Comment: What do you mean by "access"? Are they allowed to read the source code?

Comment: @Shark how can i handle permissons in your case?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen they can clone and commit on their projects. But it will be good to check their push requests. So i can cancel the wrong pushes.
they should not able to see any other than their projects.

Comment: if each project is a separate repo, then it's pretty simple no? similar for submodules as well, since each submodule is a repo of it's own as well.

Comment: Why not simply create one repository per project, and give access to those depending on the developer? The developer would then have to clone the repositories they want to work on. I assume that if a developer doesn't have access to project A, that project cannot be necessary to have locally for the other projects to work.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen It is good idea for few project. In future there will be more project, so it will be hard to track every repo. Reason of why i want only 1 repo is i can check which developer did what in a day or week, which project is worked etc..

Comment: You will have to check what your hosting solution allows for access rights. Git by itself does not have access rights built in, other than authenticating with the remote. In other words, you cannot configure git by itself to prevent access to those repositories, it has to be done on the server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git Partial Copy Access Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48301882/git-partial-copy-access-control)