# How to give access to only part of a repo with git?

Tags: git

Assuming a single repo like this:

```
repo/
  shared_lib/
  lib_a/
  lib_b/
  lib_c/
```

For myself, I want a single main repo with everything. For an employee, I might only want to share the source code of `shared_lib` and `lib_a`. What is the best way to do this while allowing me to merge employee's code to the main single repo?

Comment: Does that help https://wincent.com/wiki/Git_repository_access_control

Comment: You could use submodules in your main repo

Comment: Also a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50066204/user-access-control-in-git and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196312/how-to-set-up-a-git-repository-where-different-users-can-only-see-certain-parts and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48301882/git-partial-copy-access-control and probably others...

Comment: @larsks none of the answers explain how to do it. the only lead I got from them were submodules, subtree or multiple repos in the same folder, which doesn't explain simply how to do it, or if it's even possible.